# No cargan datos

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

Estoy poblando `<table>` con ajax, pero no me carga nada, ni tampoco un error, probé con un alert las respuestas de Ajax y no estan vacias, ningun parámetro es null;

```
<div id="tb" style="overflow-x: auto;padding-right: 15px;">
    <table id="#tablaPendientes" class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr class="thead">
                <th>Cliente</th>
                <th>Monto</th>
                <th>Fecha</th>
                <th>Estado</th>
                <th>Detalles</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

        </tbody>
    </table>
    <div id="ttb"></div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
function nombreFCl(i, ls, c, j) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'nombreCl',
        type: 'GET',
        data: {id: i},
        success: function (r) {
            var bm = "<button type='button' style='width: 100%' class='btn btn-primary' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#modalDetalle' onclick='detalle(" + ls.factura.idFactura + ")'><i class='fa fa-cogs'></i><label>Detalles</label></button>";
            $("#tablaPendientes").append("<tr><th>" + r.l + "</th><th>" + (ls.factura.montoF - ls.factura.descuentoF) + "</th><th>" + ls.factura.fechaEf + "</th><th>" + ls.factura.estadoF + "</th><th>" + bm + "</th></tr>");

        }
    });
}
```

**Respuesta**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Si te fijas en la url del ajax no tienes una url valida del servicio donde quieres recuperar los datos.

Comment: ¿cómo?, pero si ya tengo los datos, estoy usando JAVA, los datos existen, pero no me carga el TABLE, ni siquiera sale error

Comment: Los datos llega al metodo success?

Comment: claro que si, llegan al success, pero no carga nada al <table>

Answer (score 2):

Estas tratando de insertar un tr en la definición de la tabla y no en el body de la misma:

**En tu HTML:**

En el id de la tabla, elimina la almohadilla:

```
<table id="#tablaPendientes">
```

por esto:

```
<table id="tablaPendientes">
```

**Cambia esta linea de codigo:**

```
$("#tablaPendientes").append("<tr><th>" + r.l + "</th><th>" + (ls.factura.montoF - ls.factura.descuentoF) + "</th><th>" + ls.factura.fechaEf + "</th><th>" + ls.factura.estadoF + "</th><th>" + bm + "</th></tr>");
```

**Por esta:**

```
$("#tablaPendientes tbody").append("<tr><th>" + r.l + "</th><th>" + (ls.factura.montoF - ls.factura.descuentoF) + "</th><th>" + ls.factura.fechaEf + "</th><th>" + ls.factura.estadoF + "</th><th>" + bm + "</th></tr>");
```

Comment: continua igual, sin errores, sin nada; tambien probé si no instanciaba, el table, pero lo hace

Comment: puedes postear lo que te devuelve el servicio ajax en el metodo success?

Comment: lo tengo, este era el problema `id="#tablaPendientes"`

Comment: Lo acabo de ver, actualizaré mi respuesta con la solución. Que bueno que te haya funcionado.